# No internet - email notification

Tags: bash, email, ping

In fact I have 2 routers both configured with a DDNS acccount.

I wanted to setup a script, whereby I can send email notification in case internet service is down on the router.

For example,

ping router1.ddns.net , gets reply, internet is OK.
ping router2.ddns.net, no reply, internet not OK, sends an email notification.

Note I do have a firewall, but it does not have the capability to send notification if internet service is down.

Comment: I hope you are not going to send the email via internet, if internet is down?

Comment: That's why I have 2 routers. If one fails, the other one takes over.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `mailx` (my preference since it is the easiest)

```
echo "this is the body of the email" | mailx -vvv -s "test mail" -r "From" -S smtp="your-smtp" someone@address
```

gmail configuration example

vi ~/.mailrc

```
account gmail {
    set smtp-use-starttls
    set ssl-verify=ignore
    set smtp-auth=login
    set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
    set from="noreply@yourdomain.com(Your Real Name)"
    set smtp-auth-user=noreply@yourdomain.com
    set smtp-auth-password=your_less_secure_apps_password
    set ssl-verify=ignore
}
```

then

```
echo -e "Mail body text" | mailx -A gmail -s "Mail subject" your@email
```

Comment: I know how to send email. 
My question was to get an idea how to start the code.